# Combine 2 tables with common variables but no common observations

Tags: r, match

I would like to match 2 Data sets (tables) which only have some (not all) variables in common but not any of those obs. - So actually I want to add dataset1 to dataset2, adding the column names of dataset2, while in empty fields of the table should be filled in with NA.
So what I did is, I tried the following function;

```
matchcol = function(x,y){
  y = y[,match(colnames(x),colnames(y))]
  colnames(y)=colnames(x)
  return(y)
}


sum =matchcol(dataset1,dataset2)

data = rbind(dataset1,dataset2)
```

But I get; "Error: NA columns indexes not supported.
What can I do? What can I change in my code.

Thx!!

Comment: Maybe `dplyr::bind_rows`?

Comment: The question is slightly confusing, do you want to take just the column names of second dataset and add them to first dataset with the value of "NA" if that column is not already present in first dataset?

Answer (score 1):

To use `rbind` you need to have the same column names, but with `bind_rows` from `dplyr` package you don't, try this:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- bind_rows(dataset1, dataset2)
```

example :

```
dataset1 <- data.frame(a= 1:5,b=6:10)
dataset2 <- data.frame(a= 11:15,c=16:20)
data <- bind_rows(dataset1,dataset2)
#     a  b  c
# 1   1  6 NA
# 2   2  7 NA
# 3   3  8 NA
# 4   4  9 NA
# 5   5 10 NA
# 6  11 NA 16
# 7  12 NA 17
# 8  13 NA 18
# 9  14 NA 19
# 10 15 NA 20
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question right, it looks like dplyr::full_join is good for that:

```
library(dplyr)    
dataset1 <- data.frame(Var_A = 1:10, Var_B = 100:109)    
dataset2 <- data.frame(Var_A = 11:20, Var_C = 200:209)    
dataset_new <- full_join(dataset1, dataset2)    
dataset_new
```

This will automatically join the two datasets by common column names and add all other columns from both datasets. And empty fields are NAs.

Does that work for you?

Comment: The OP specified that the two datasets have no observations in common, and seems to be essentially stacking the data frames. `full_join` could be dangerous if the two datasets have any values in common on the merged columns. I think `bind_rows` is the safer option here

Comment: Nevertheless it solves the described problem. There is no information provided, how "common observations" should be treated. If you think about an ID, most of the time you want a join, not several observations with the same ID.

Comment: If you have an ID variable to join on, I agree with you. However, the OP makes no mention of an ID variable to prevent potentially undesired merges. In general, I find merging/joining without specifically stating the 'by' variables to be a risky proposition, but that's a whole different conversation